# Cognos 11.1.7 asterisk appearing in a calculated field. How do I tell Cognos not to show the asterisk?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I have a calculated field in a crosstab formatted as a percent with 1 decimal place
The calculation works fine
The results however show an asterisk (after the percent sign) even when exported to Excel

What I have found on some web searches is Cognos shows an asterisk when the unit of measure is unknown. Not sure if this applies to what I am doing with Cognos

The calculation is B divided by A

[image: asterisk image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the (annoying) issue (in a crosstab column) by:

- Define content of the Crosstab intersection: yes
- Unlock report
- Drag and drop in the cell a Text Box
- Change the textbox Source Type to Report Expression
- Insert the calculation as a Report Expression instead of a query calculation

Comment: If you have access to FWM (Framework Manager) or you are using data modules.  Check to see if the format types are different.  If so, make sure they are the same format (i.e. currency, etc).  That also solves the issue.  Give it a try and let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, set the format to custom and enter the data pattern

For example,

```
##0.0%
```